# c++ async multiple tasks implementation

Tags: c#, c++, async-await

I have used the tasks in c# in this way:

```
static async Task<string> DoTaskAsync(string name, int timeout)
{
   var start = DateTime.Now;
   Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}, {1}", name, timeout);
   await Task.Delay(timeout);
   Console.WriteLine("Exit {0}, {1}", name, (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
   return name;
}

public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var t1 = DoTaskAsync("t2.1", 3000);
    var t2 = DoTaskAsync("t2.2", 2000);
    var t3 = DoTaskAsync("t2.3", 1000);

    return Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

but I need to do the some in c++.

There is a way to migrate this code in c++ ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are several options for a direct translation, but rarely is a direct translation the right solution. Instead assess the behaviour you want on a grander scale and see if C++ offers a different path to attaining it that will serve your goals better.

Comment: Do you want C++ or C++/CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more or less direct translation would probably use C++ [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)s returned by [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Disclaimer: I don't have bit of C# knowledge and just read about its `Task`s a bit just now. I *think* this is what you are going for.

- In C++ we use [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)s instead of plain `int`s. The resolution of the clocks is often much higher than milliseconds, so I selected to go for whatever duration the [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) supports. You can thereby pass it a `std::chrono::milliseconds` or `std::chrono::seconds` - and it will do the right thing.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <chrono>    // clocks and durations
#include <format>    // std::format
#include <future>    // std::async
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>    // std::this_thread::sleep_for

auto DoTaskAsync(std::string name, std::chrono::steady_clock::duration timeout)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async,
        [name=std::move(name),timeout] {
            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::cout << std::format("Enter {0}, {1}\n", name, timeout);

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);
            
            std::cout << std::format("Exit {0}, {1}\n", name,
                std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                    std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start));
            
            return name;
        });
}

std::array<std::string, 3> DoSomethingAsync() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto t1 = DoTaskAsync("t2.1", 3000000000ns); // nanoseconds
    auto t2 = DoTaskAsync("t2.2", 2000ms);       // milliseconds
    auto t3 = DoTaskAsync("t2.3", 1s);           // seconds
    return {t1.get(), t2.get(), t3.get()};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eT64GMYrE)

Comment: Side note: You have to be compiling against the C++20 Standard to get all the goodies used here, so at this time you'll need a fairly up-to-date compiler and almost certainly have to select C++20 with a compiler option.

Comment: @user4581301 Absolutely. I wanted to stay as close to OPs code as possible so I threw things in that my normal compiler doesn't even support. At least MSVC supports it all. It's probably not long before the other vendors catch up. :-) C++20 should be default for any new project though so I don't see that as a big problem.

Comment: Still clawing my way up to C++17 as the minimum for new projects. Tooling for some of the stuff I work on is sparse.

Comment: @user4581301 Tell me about it. I have to fight gcc 4.7.3 on a daily basis. It doesn't even know `thread_local`, much less C++17.

Comment: Thank you this is what I need. However I have C++17. The content of DoTaskAsync is only and example can be only Print("Hello word"). There is a way to extend compatibility with  C++17 ?

Comment: @marcoluca987 You're welcome. Juat remove the inclusion of the `format` header and all uses of `std::format` in the code and it should be working in C++17.